# Permission denied while running startup.sh in linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I am trying to run tomcat 6 in linux when I invoke startup.sh I see this error in catalina.out

```
/home/***/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/bin/catalina.sh: line 338: /home/***/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
```

How can I get it running ? please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /home/***/jre/bin/
$ chmod +x java
```

and then do:

```
$ sudo startup.sh
```

Answer (score 12):

Go to that folder and type the following code.

```
chmod 777 *
```

and try running it.

Its because of the permissions set.

If you are specific with permissions give excecute permission to it.
                                     Or

```
cd home/
chmod 777 apache-tomcat6.0
cd apache-tomcat6.0/bin
sh startup.sh
```

Comment: This works, but why this happens?

Comment: Good @Govan, worked for me too, thx

Comment: It worked great, thanks. But is there no security issues to that cos as i followed from digital ocean, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04, they used different permissions for the various files and folders.

Comment: It depends on what permission you need to give

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at where it is outputting the logs for starting up your java process and ensure the user that is trying to start it has permissions to write to it - you can try running java as the current user which should work and point the issue at being the explained